# Package Autoloading Issues

Tags: php, package, composer-php

I'm struggling to work out how to correctly build and autoload my first composer package. I understand that if I follow the PSR-0 naming convention, autoloading should "just work". I am trying to set up with:

- vendor: Programster
- package name: CoreLibs

I have managed to debug a project that includes the package to the point where I am outputting the search path by putting a print in the `findFileWithExtension()` function of the `ClassLoader.php` file

```
/home/stuart/Desktop/test-project/vendor/Programster/CoreLibs/Programster/Programster/CoreLibs/Core.php
```

I know that the file is actually located at:

```
/home/stuart/Desktop/test-project/vendor/Programster/CoreLibs/Core.php
```

My Package's composer.json file:

```
{
    "name": "Programster/CoreLibs",
    "type": "library",
    "description": "Core libraries for PHP 5.3+",
    "keywords": ["core","library"],
    "homepage": "http://svn.yadda-yadda.com/php/core-libs",
    "license": "none",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "xxxx",
            "email": "my.email@email.com",
            "homepage": "http://mywebsite.com/",
            "role": "Developer"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
            "Programster": "Programster"
        }
    }
}
```

The following is a tiny script in a project that includes the package to test if is working:

```
<?php

require_once(__DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php');

$loader = new \Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader();
$loader->register();

use \Programster\CoreLibs as programster;
programster\Core::println("hello world");
```

The project's composer.json file to include the package:

```
{
    "repositories": [ { "type": "composer", "url": "http://satis.mydomain.com/" } ],
    "require": {
        "Programster/CoreLibs": "dev-trunk"
    }
}
```

Is my package's config wrong, or do I really need to create Programster/CoreLibs/ subdirectories within the CoreLibs repository source code?

Comment: PSR-0 is deprecated, you might want to use the friendlier PSR-4 instead.

Comment: @yo , cannot find message about deprecation of PSR-0. Could you share some links about it for me?

Comment: Are you searching for advice or for fixing some issue?

Comment: Well, maybe "deprecated" isn't the right word, but PSR-4 is cleaner nonetheless and was designed with composer in mind. Projects like Drupal have already adopted it. https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-4-autoloader-meta.md

Comment: @sectus I'm trying to find the solution to fixing the autoloading of my package. Perhaps this requires a configuration change, or a change to the directory structure.

Comment: 1. `$loader = new \Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader();$loader->register();` -- useless 2. Have you installed your application?

Comment: @yo PSR-0 is NOT deprecated, because it is the only way to autoload classes that do not use namespaces - and this will probably never be deprecated. You are however right that PSR-4 allow to use shorter path names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it working by using the PSR-4 standard that others suggested in the comments and updating my package's composer.json file (see the autoload section):

```
{
    "name": "Programster/CoreLibs",
    "type": "library",
    "description": "Core libraries for PHP 5.3+",
    "keywords": ["core","library"],
    "homepage": "http://svn.mydomain/core-libs",
    "license": "none",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "MY name",
            "email": "my.email@email.com",
            "homepage": "http://my-website.com/",
            "role": "Developer"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Programster\\CoreLibs\\": ""
        }
    }
}
```

This is my script in the project that has the package installed:

```
require_once(__DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php');
\Programster\CoreLibs\Core::println("hello world");
```

@sectus was right, I did not need to use `$loader = new \Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader();$loader->register();`

Answer (score 1):

```
use \Programster\CoreLibs as programster;
programster\Core::println("hello world");
```

Your class name evaluates to `\Programster\CoreLibs\Core`.

With this PSR-0 autoloading,

```
    "psr-0": {
        "Programster": "Programster"
    }
```

the class name will be completely converted into a path name like "Programster/CoreLibs/Core.php", and this path will be searched inside the directory "Programster" relative to your libraries `composer.json` location.

Using PSR-4 autoloading,

```
    "psr-4": {
        "Programster\\CoreLibs\\": ""
    }
```

the prefix in this definition will be removed from the classname, the remainder will be converted to a path (i.e. "Core.php") and be searched in the path mentioned (in this case, in the main directory of the library, because "" + "Core.php" is pointing to a file in without any sub directory).

Your second definition is better in some regards. It uses a longer prefix, which is relevant if you include more than one library using the same prefix, because then Composer would have to search more than one path to find the class. And it uses a shorter path, which also allows for slightly faster disk I/O operations (I haven't done any performance measurements, though).

Comment: thanks for the info. With regards to `if you include more than one library using the same prefix` my intention is that I will have another library later called Programster\\Package2 etc. This should hopefully get "merged" so that there the directory structure will be `vendor/Programster/CoreLibs` and `vendor/Programster/Package2`

Comment: Unless Composer gets changes in how it organizes the libraries (which is nothing you should worry about because it is not your business - you have to care only about being able to autoload the classes), the current model is to create a "vendorname/packagename" sub folder for every package that is included.